# I want to merge some images at start and end of video to generate new video

Tags: php, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am working on small project where i need to merge some images at start and end of existing video.
At start of video i need to merge one image and at the end of video there will be multiple images merged.
After merging the video the output file will be the video file having those images embeded as video.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789881/video-editing-using-php

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided much details and as per you question I think it is complicated but I would suggest you to combine all of those videos into one let say -

I. You have created a image and then convert that image to video.

First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For example, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg,...

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
```

You can refer - [**How do I encode single pictures into movies?**](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)

II. Then you have to merge created videos and existing videos into one. You can refer [**How-can-I-concatenate-video-files**](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f)

For full information you can refer **[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html)**

I hope this will help you, at least guide you to right direction.